# Pandas groupby countif with dynamic columns

Tags: python, pandas, sum, multiple-columns, mean

I have a dataframe with this structure:

```
time,10.0.0.103,10.0.0.24
2016-10-12 13:40:00,157,172
2016-10-12 14:00:00,0,203
2016-10-12 14:20:00,0,0
2016-10-12 14:40:00,0,200
2016-10-12 15:00:00,185,208
```

It details the number of events per IP address for a given 20 minute period. I need a dataframe of how many 20 minute periods per miner had 0 events, from which I need to derive IP 'uptime' as a percent. The number of IP addresses is dynamic. Desired output:

```
IP,noEvents,uptime
10.0.0.103,3,40
10.0.0.24,1,80
```

I have tried with groupby, agg and lambda to no avail. What is the best way of doing a 'countif' by dynamic columns?

Comment: If miner IP `10.0.0.103` has 3 periods (out of 5) with no accidents, shouldn't his uptime be 60%?

Comment: Well, yes. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) of boolean mask by condition `df == 0`. Last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) both `Series`:

```
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
mask = (df == 0)
print (mask)
                    10.0.0.103 10.0.0.24
time                                    
2016-10-12 13:40:00      False     False
2016-10-12 14:00:00       True     False
2016-10-12 14:20:00       True      True
2016-10-12 14:40:00       True     False
2016-10-12 15:00:00      False     False

noEvents = mask.sum()
print (noEvents)
10.0.0.103    3
10.0.0.24     1
dtype: int64

uptime = 100 * mask.mean()
print (uptime)
10.0.0.103    60.0
10.0.0.24     20.0
dtype: float64

print (pd.concat([noEvents, uptime], axis=1, keys=('noEvents','uptime'))
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'index':'IP'}))

           IP  noEvents  uptime
0  10.0.0.103         3    60.0
1   10.0.0.24         1    20.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Transpose the `DF`:

```
df = df.T
```

Since you tried along the lines of using `groupby`, you could further proceed using [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get the count of zeros in every group after stacking it to produce a `series` object and later unstack it back to the `DF` as shown:

```
grp = df.stack().to_frame('val').groupby(level=0)['val']
df['noEvents'] = grp.value_counts().unstack()[0]
```

Later, divide the values with the size of that group to get it's percentage distribution:

```
df['upTime'] = (100*df['noEvents']/grp.size())
```

For Aesthetic purpose:

```
df = df[['noEvents', 'upTime']].astype(int)
df.index.name = 'IP'
df.columns.name = None
df
```

[image]